# how to access a non static member variable using scope resolution operator in php?

Tags: php, oop

In php using :: we can access a non static member function , but how can i access the member variable same using scope resolution operator ?

```html
<?php 
class abc
{
    public static $data="i am static membervaribale".'</br>';

    public $data1="i am not a static membervaribale".'</br>';
    public   function a()
    {
        echo "I am a non static method".'</br>';
    }

    public  function getsize()
    {
        return self::$data;
    }
}

echo abc::$data;

//echo abc::$data1;//showing error;

echo abc::a();

echo abc::getsize();

$obj=new abc;
echo $obj->data1;


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the access to not static  member  the class is based on $this.
So you should use

```
 $this->data1;
```

and for a new object   of the class abc()

```
 $myObejct = new abc();

 $myObject->data1;
```

Comment: can we access using scope resolution operator like what we are doing for non static method?

Comment: no you must instance an object based on class using new and access to the related  property ..